# Add arrow below x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

How can I add an arrow next to the x and y axis titles, such as the picture below?

[image]

```
quadrant <- ggplot(quadrants, aes(x=Ampolla, y=Energia, label=Branca_percIPI))+
  coord_fixed() +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(-5, 50)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,50))+
   geom_vline(xintercept = 11.3, color = "grey50", size=1.2) +
   geom_hline(yintercept = 17.7, color = "grey50", size=1.2) +
  geom_text_repel(size = 7,
                   colour = "#2896BA",
                   min.segment.length = Inf, hjust="right", nudge_x=0.9, nudge_y=1.5, force=1,
                  arrow = arrow(length=unit(0.5,"cm"), ends="first"), lineheight = 1)+
  geom_point(colour="#2896BA", size=3.5)+
  labs(title = "Incidència dels colls d'ampolla i dependència energètica total",
       subtitle="(% de variació interanual de l'IPI*, % d'empreses afectades pels colls d'ampolla i % de dependència energètica)",
       x = "Colls d'ampolla (% d'empreses afectades)**",
       y = "Dependència energètica total (%)")+
  annotation_custom(segmentsGrob(c(0.3, -0.1), c(-0.085, 0.28), 
                                 c(1, -0.1), c(-0.085, 0.28), gp = gpar(lwd = 2),
                                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(2.5, 'mm'))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can turn clipping off inside `coord_cartesian` and add custom annotations for the arrows using `segmentsGrob` from the `grid` package inside `annotation_custom`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point(color = '#2896ba') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 5.5, color = 'gray50') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.8, color = 'gray50') +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(hjust = 0),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  annotation_custom(segmentsGrob(c(0.3, -0.1), c(-0.085, 0.28), 
                                 c(1, -0.1), c(-0.085, 1), gp = gpar(lwd = 2),
                                arrow = arrow(length = unit(2.5, 'mm')))) +
  labs(caption = paste0("Here is a very long caption to demonstrate that ",
                        "it is possible\nto add a very long caption ",
                        'underneath the x axis, thereby\n',
                        'emulating the caption in the plot in the question.'),
       title = 'Another iris plot', subtitle = 'Just in case you need one')
```

[image]

Comment: It worked for the x axis, but not for the y axis.

Comment: @Maria it does work (see above). Perhaps try making your plot larger by dragging the plotting window or changing the co-ordinates of the arrow segments inside `segmentsGrob`